# SELinux: Why can httpd read files in /var/www/html?

Tags: selinux

I'm just trying to understand targeted SELinux better. While I understand that users, processes, ports etc. are labled with a quadruple `<user>,role>,<type>,<sensitivity>` and how to set the labels using `semanage, restorecon` etc. I don't yet understand how SELinux decides if a resource is accessible from from a process and how it can be accessed by the process.

For example looking at my `httpd` on REL8 I can see the following labels on the process and the default `DocumentRoot` directory `/var/www/html`:

```
[root@mylinux targeted]# ls -alZ /var/www/html
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0  6 Aug 17 16:53 .
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 33 Aug 17 16:53 ..

[root@mylinux targeted]# ps -efZ | grep httpd
system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0    root       35291       1  0 13:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0    apache     35292   35291  0 13:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0    apache     35293   35291  0 13:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0    apache     35294   35291  0 13:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0    apache     35295   35291  0 13:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 root 35838 27088  0 13:30 pts/0 00:00:00 grep --color=auto httpd
```

But what I'm looking for are answers to the following questions:

1. *Why is the httpd process allowed to access the files in /var/www/html*? Which labels are checked here in which order and which labels must match?
2. *What does the `role` defining that this access is permitted look like*? How can I check the role definition
3. *How can I determine how a process can access a resource of a specific label*?
4. *Can I as an admin modify the role so that for example other file contexts can be accessed as well*?

Thanks a lot in advance for any clarificaton.

Comment: An excellent and well written question. But although you cite  a specific use-case what you're asking is a almost complete breakdown on how SELinux works which IMHO is too broad to answer in our Q&A format. That's why I'm voting to close your question. - The short answer: the SELinux policy is what ties everything together .- The kernel enforces the use of an SELinux policy to evaluate access requests on the system. By default, SELinux denies all requests except for requests that correspond to the rules specified in the loaded policy.

Comment: Writing your own SELinux policies might be a useful approach to find the answers to your questions, for example https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_selinux/writing-a-custom-selinux-policy_using-selinux

Comment: Well I know it is complex but hoped that someone with a better understanding could provide a walk thru of the steps SELinux performs (hence the  concrete example).

Comment: The things you describe are inputs to a rules engine with (the last time I checked) over 180,000 lines of config. Like HBrujin, I think that describing the behaviour of this is way beyond the scope of serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

From your output:

```
[root@mylinux targeted]# ps -efZ | grep httpd
system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0    root       35291       1  0 13:23 ?
```

`httpd` runs as `httpd_t` label. Such label is attached to the process via a specific selinux domain transition rule.

Then, as we can see:

```
[root@mylinux targeted]# ls -alZ /var/www/html
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0  6 Aug 17 16:53 .
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 33 Aug 17 16:53 ..
```

`/var/www/html` has the allowed domain label `httpd_sys_content_t`. Hence a process running with `httpd_d` can read filesystem content labeled with the same `httpd_sys_content_t`.

All this is controlled via very complex (and verbose) selinux rules. Sysadmins are not expected to understand the entire ruleset, so don't panic. What is important is to understand is a) selinux logs, b) `semanage` and c) `audit2allow`

For more information, you can read [RedHat Selinux docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/it-it/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_selinux/getting-started-with-selinux_using-selinux)

To reply to your questions:

1. *Why is the httpd process allowed to access the files in /var/www/html?* Because a rule permits a process with `httpd_t` label to read files with the `httpd_sys_content_t` label (ie: `ALLOW apache_process apache_log:FILE READ;`)
2. *What does the role defining that this access is permitted look like?* Roles applies MAC to user types (ie: staff), but are not used in the default policy; rather, they are used in the (non-default) MLS policy.
3. *How can I determine how a process can access a resource of a specific label?* You can dump the entire policy set, but this is not going to provide simple information. Rather, give a look at `semange fcontext -l`
4. *Can I as an admin modify the role so that for example other file contexts can be accessed as well?* Sure. You can write a policy from scratch (not recommended) or use `audit2allow` (better). However, try to avoid this as any custom policy change will be difficult to track/manage; rather, when possible, use `setsebool` or `semanage` to customize your base policy.

Comment: Where do you see that /var/www/html has the same domain label httpd_t? Isn't it httpd_sys_content_t? What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, it is `httpd_sys_content_t`, I misread the label, sorry. Still, what I wrote applies: a rule enables such domain to interact with the specified file label.